# NavigationDrawerFragment not working with AppCompat Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm using the NavigationDrawer created by the template (when starting a new project).
I'm trying to get Material Design compatibility so I'm using AppCompat v7.
I followed [these instructions](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) to set a Toolbar as my ActionBar (i.e. using setSupportActionBar on my toolbar) and I get a NPE in my NavigationDrawerFragment at (inside onCreateView)

```
 mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1, ...
```

now I suspect the issues is with the getActionBar() method inside fragment:

```
   private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}
```

but I have no idea why - I called setSupportActionBar(toolbar) in Activity's onCreate before calling setUp() on the NavigationDrawerFragment...

If anyone has a clue why this is happening please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the problem was that fragment's onCreateView was called before activity's onCreate and thus there was no ActionBar set. I just moved the problematic code into fragment's onActivityCreated and it works like a charm.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: @bernlim 
Sure. The problem was that when my activity was being created the fragment's onCreateView method was called before activity's onCreate. The NPE arises in fragment's onCreateView because I try to get the action bar which is null at that point as activity's onCreate hasn't been called yet and so ActionBar hasn't been initialized/set/created yet.
Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

just replace `getActionBar().getThemedContext()` with `getActivity()`

Comment: but getActivity() is not equivalent of getActionBar().getThemedContext() though it can give context.